# Unable to resolve runtime.ubuntu in dotnet restore

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

I have dotnet 1.0.0-preview2-003131 installed on my Windows 7 machine.  When I run the command `dotnet restore` using cmd in the directory of my .NET Core project, I get these errors:

```
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Projects\TestDotNetCore\Test2\project.json...
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostP
olicy (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.Cor
eCLR (>= 1.0.4)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostR
esolver (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Jit (>= 1.0
.4)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System (>= 1.0
.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Net.Sec
urity (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Securit
y.Cryptography (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Net.Htt
p (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost
(>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
error: Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.IO.Comp
ression (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\Projects\Te
stDotNetCore\Test2\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Projects\TestDotNetCore\Test2\project.json
log  : Restore failed in 1315ms.

Errors in C:\Projects\TestDotNetCore\Test2\project.json
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPoli
cy (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCL
R (>= 1.0.4)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostReso
lver (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Jit (>= 1.0.4)
' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System (>= 1.0.1)
' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Net.Securi
ty (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.C
ryptography (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.Net.Http (
>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost (>=
 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
    Unable to resolve 'runtime.ubuntu.16.04-x64.runtime.native.System.IO.Compres
sion (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (ubuntu.16.04-x64)'.
```

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "debugType": "portable",
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "version": "1.0.1"
        }
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"

        }
    },
    "runtimes": {
        "win7-x64": {},
        "ubuntu.16.04-x64": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you comment this line `"ubuntu.16.04-x64": {}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `runtimes` section of your `project.json` file, or at least the `ubuntu.16.04-x64` line.

Unless you are building a [self-contained application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd), you don't need the `runtimes` section.

Comment: I have the same error, but I have no project.json file. The error occurs in an integration test project. I've done a global search but can't find any occurrence of 'ubuntu' in any file. What could be other reasons for this error?

Comment: @Diana I recommend posting a new question. Be sure to incude your `.csproj` file. My guess is the problem is there.